# Store and recover nested Backbone models into local storage

Tags: javascript, view, backbone.js, nested, models

I'm looking for creating a complex backbone model architecture as :

- Backbone Model A

  - Backbone Model B1 (in A)

    - Collection Model C (in B1)
  - Backbone Model B2 (in A)

I wish to nest Backbone Models for the following reasons :

- I have a global view that will display information present in A and B
- I have a view that displays all  B1 attributes

In the end, I wanted one Backbone model for one view, but I must save a collection of A only into the  local storage.

**For now my principle is as follows :**

When initializing A :

- In initalize() of A model I set :

  ```
  this.attributes.modelB = new ModelB();
  ```

For the moment, if I create an object modelA, I can access a B attribute as follows :

```
modelA.attributes.modelB.get ('id') 
// or 
modelA.attributes.modelB.attributes.id
```

*In fact it's just a nested backbone model object*

Let's store A into local storage for a later use :

- I add A to my collection *“itemsCollection”*
- I save A with *save()*

Let's take a look into the local storage :

```
localStorage.getItem ("itemsCollection")
```

Added A object is fully json parsed, as if by calling the method *save()*, each level of Backbone object into A model perform a *toJSON()*.

All fields are well stored.

Now I need to read this object to display the content in my view.

- I create a collection *"itemsCollection"* then I call method *fetch()*.

Disaster, only the first level is recovered, over level are reset as empty B models.

Something tells me the *fetch()* method wasn't made for recovering nested backbone model.
But, my model pattern is simple and common, I need objects in objects, my solution may not be correct.

**Do you have any suggestion for me ?**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

True, Backbone will *not* cater for nested models (models-within-models):

> Backbone doesn't include direct support for nested models and collections or "has many" associations because there are a number of good patterns for modeling structured data on the client side, *and Backbone should provide the foundation for implementing any of them*.

You can read all about it [here](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-nested) where some suggestions are also offered.